# ServiceStack Session Time Increase

Tags: c#

How to increase session time. It logs out after 10 min, but I need to extend it up to 2 hours.

My code:

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase AuthService, IAuthSession Session, IOAuthTokens Tokens, Dictionary<string, string> AuthInfo) {
    try { 
        base.OnAuthenticated(AuthService, Session, Tokens, AuthInfo);

        //var Manager = new ArbProManager(false, 0, "ArbProService");
        //fwkArbProMobile.dbContext.EntityUserAccount User;

        string dbName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MasterDatabase"];
        DAL.MobileUser usrContext = new DAL.MobileUser(dbName);
        Types.MobileUser User = usrContext.GetForEmail(Session.UserAuthName);

         // User = Manager.UserAccountInstance(Session.UserAuthName);
         Session.UserAuthId = User.Id.ToString();
         Session.DisplayName = User.EmailAddress;
         Session.Email = User.ClientDatabaseName;
         Session.Sequence = User.UserGuid.ToString();
         //var session = AuthService.GetSession();
         //AuthService.SaveSession(session, TimeSpan.FromDays(100));

         //AuthService.SaveSession(Session, SessionExpiry);
         //var sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(AuthService.GetSessionId());
         //redis.ExpireEntryIn(sessionKey, slidingExpiry); 
         //new CredentialsAuthProvider { SessionExpiry = TimeSpan.FromDays(10) };
         //AuthService.SaveSession(Session, SessionExpiry);
         Logger.InfoFormat("ArbProAuthProvider:UserId {0} logged in as {1}", Session.UserAuthId, Session.DisplayName);
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
         Logger.ErrorFormat("OnAuthenticated:Error='{0}'", ex.ToString());
         throw ex;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why have you commented out the `AuthService.SaveSession` lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session expiry value starts off ok, then changes to default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148028/session-expiry-value-starts-off-ok-then-changes-to-default)

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way to control [Session](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) lifetimes in ServiceStack is by intercepting each time a Session is saved and change what Session Expiry it's saved with by overriding `OnSaveSession` in your `AppHost`:

```
public override void OnSaveSession(
    IRequest httpReq, IAuthSession session, TimeSpan? expiresIn = null)
{
    var customExpiry = ...
    base.OnSaveSession(httpReq, session, customExpiry);
}
```